# Fixed Intervals on MSChart Axis

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I have a windows forms project in VS2010 with a simple line chart.

The data is dynamic and always ranging between 1.4000 and 1.5000.

I want the Y axis's gridlines/labels to always be displayed **on every** #.##20 data point, as in:

1.4080 ----------------------------

1.4060 ----------------------------

1.4040 ----------------------------

1.4020 ----------------------------

1.4000 ----------------------------

etc.

So I tried the Interval property for the axis gridlines/labels, setting it to 0.002, and the result was that the gridlines/labels were displayed ***every*** 0.0020 points, like for example this:

1.4084 ----------------------------

1.4064 ----------------------------

1.4044 ----------------------------

1.4024 ----------------------------

1.4004 ----------------------------

but not ***on*** 0.0020 points too as shown previously.

Any suggestions on how to get it to be displayed the way I want?

Comment: Are you referring to the new [Chart Controls for .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14422) or the legacy MSChart ActiveX? I haven't been able to reproduce your problem with the new controls -- the Y axis on the line chart should automatically round down to 1.400, unless you set an explicit Minimum of 1.4004.

Comment: @brianpeiris I am referring to the microsoft chart control included in VS2010 (.NET 4.0). The Minimum/Maximum are set to the lowest/highest values of the displayed data, which is dynamic. Under those conditions, I want to still have the labels/gridlines displayed the way I described (i.e. on 0.0020 points). I find it strange that something this simple seems impossible, I could easily do it in Excel's charts for instance.

Comment: What is the reason for setting the Minimum? If you don't then it will automatically choose 1.4000 for you. If you must set the Minimum explicitly, then you must round it down to the next 0.020 yourself.

Comment: @brianpeiris Looks like that's the only way to go. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

In your `AxisY`, set the `Minimum` value to 1.4004, `Maximum` value to 1.4084(or the corresponding minimum/maximum value rounded to 4 decimal places pulled from your dynamic data), `Interval` to 0.0020 and `IntervalAutoMode` to `FixedCount`. Also, set the axis' `LabelStyle`'s `Format` to {0.0000} to have four decimal places of rounding in the label.

Comment: I think the OP wanted 3 decimal places but this is a good answer.